# Split large CSV file based on row value

Tags: python, csv

### The porblem

I have a csv file called `data.csv`. On each row I have:

```
timestamp: int
account_id: int
data: float
```

for instance:

```
timestamp,account_id,value
10,0,0.262
10,0,0.111
13,1,0.787
14,0,0.990
```

- This file is ordered by timestamp.
- The number of row is too big to store all rows in memory.
- order of magnitude: 100 M rows, number of account: 5 M

**How can I quickly get all rows of a given account_id ? What would be the best way to make the data accessible by account_id ?**

### Things I tried

to generate a sample:

```
N_ROW = 10**6
N_ACCOUNT = 10**5

# Generate data to split
with open('./data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
  csv_file.write('timestamp,account_id,value\n')
  for timestamp in tqdm.tqdm(range(N_ROW), desc='writing csv file to split'):
    account_id = random.randint(1,N_ACCOUNT)
    data = random.random()
    csv_file.write(f'{timestamp},{account_id},{data}\n')

# Clean result folder
if os.path.isdir('./result'):
  shutil.rmtree('./result')
os.mkdir('./result')
```

#### Solution 1

Write a script that creates a file for each account, read rows one by one on the original csv, write the row on on the file that corresponds to the account (open and close a file for each row).

**Code:**

```
# Split the data
p_bar = tqdm.tqdm(total=N_ROW, desc='splitting csv file')
with open('./data.csv') as data_file:
  next(data_file) # skip header
  for row in data_file:
    account_id = row.split(',')[1]
    account_file_path = f'result/{account_id}.csv'
    file_opening_mode = 'a' if os.path.isfile(account_file_path) else 'w'
    with open(account_file_path, file_opening_mode) as account_file:
      account_file.write(row)
    p_bar.update(1)
```

**Issues:**

It is quite slow (i think it is inefficient to open and close a file on each row). It takes around 4 minutes for 1 M rows. Even if it works, will it be fast ? Given an account_id I know the name of the file I should read but the system has to look over 5M files to find it. Should I create some kind of binary tree with folders with the leafs being the files ?

#### Solution 2 (works on small example not on large csv file)

Same idea as solution 1 but instead of opening / closing a file for each row, store files in a dictionary

**Code:**

```
# A dict that will contain all files
account_file_dict = {}

# A function given an account id, returns the file to write in (create new file if do not exist)
def get_account_file(account_id):
  file = account_file_dict.get(account_id, None)
  if file is None:
    file = open(f'./result/{account_id}.csv', 'w')
    account_file_dict[account_id] = file
    file.__enter__()
  return file

# Split the data
p_bar = tqdm.tqdm(total=N_ROW, desc='splitting csv file')
with open('./data.csv') as data_file:
  next(data_file) # skip header
  for row in data_file:
    account_id = row.split(',')[1]
    account_file = get_account_file(account_id)
    account_file.write(row)
    p_bar.update(1)
```

**Issues:**

I am not sure it is actually faster.
I have to open simultaneously 5M files (one per account). I get an error `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: './result/33725.csv'`.

#### Solution 3 (works on small example not on large csv file)

Use `awk` command, solution from: [split large csv text file based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951393/split-large-csv-text-file-based-on-column-value)

**code:**

after generating the file, run: `awk -F, 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} {f="./result/"$2".csv"} !($2 in p) {p[$2]; print h > f} {print >> f}' ./data.csv`

**Issues:**

I get the following error: `input record number 28229, file ./data.csv source line number 1` (number 28229 is an example, it usually fails around 28k). I assume It is also because i am opening too many files

Comment: : Can you share the input your are passing and output you are expecting

Comment: As far as I know to make the process faster split the process into batch by batch

Comment: @codeholic24 The code that generates the file is given just under `Things i tired` it just creates a csv file with random data `timestamp, account_id, value`. The output of each solution is a `result` folder that contains multiple csv file, the name of the csv file is `<account_id>.csv` which stores all lines from the original csv file  that belongs the account.

Comment: @codeholic24 I did not tried to batch, it might indeed speed up the process (not sure it will speed up a lot the process though but i will try, thank you).

Comment: @VinceM : how big is the total file ? within `3 GB` `mawk2` and `gawk` probably can handle it all in memory and do it in one shot. Or use `gnu-parallel` or something to run 9 `awk`s, each given a single digit as their own customized input, and have each `awk` instance only handle `account_id`s starting with that custom digit

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto the file is around 15 GB (`data.csv` file does not contain only 3 columns, it was a simplified example). I am not an expert with `awk` (i did copy and paste solution from `split large csv text file based on column value` and adapted it for my data). I do not know what `mawk2`, `gawk`, `gnu-parallel` are but i will try to look at it.

Comment: Have you considered importing the CSV into a database and using queries and views to select (and process: sum, etc.) data by account?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Yes i did considered this solution (I was tempted to add it in the list of solution of the post). This solution would work fine but it has a downside: i need to install, set-up and populate the db. I am not alone on the project i am working on, so all other developers would have to install new dev dependencies. Worst case, i could choose this solution but if possible, i would like to avoid it and stay with just python code.

Comment: @VinceM : if u're cool with calling `awk` from within `python`, then my response below can be a rough framework for the approach i was mentioning

Comment: @VinceM have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html, it doesn't require any dependencies

Answer (score 0):

@VinceM :

While not quite `15 GB`, I do have a `7.6 GB` one with 3 columns :

-- `148 mn` prime numbers, their `base-2 log`, and their `hex`

```
  in0: 7.59GiB 0:00:09 [ 841MiB/s] [ 841MiB/s] [========>] 100%            
  
  148,156,631 lines 7773.641 MB (  8151253694)  /dev/stdin
```

|

```
f="$( grealpath -ePq ~/master_primelist_19d.txt )"

( time ( for __ in '12' '34' '56' '78' '9'; do 

     ( gawk -v ___="${__}" -Mbe 'BEGIN {

               ___="^["(___%((_+=_^=FS=OFS="=")+_*_*_)^_)"]" 

       }  ($_)~___ && ($NF = int(($_)^_))^!_' "${f}" & ) done | 

  gcat - ) ) | pvE9 > "${DT}/test_primes_squared_00000002.txt"
```

|

```
 out9: 13.2GiB 0:02:06 [98.4MiB/s] [ 106MiB/s] [ <=> ]

  ( for __ in '12' '34' '56' '78' '9'; do; ( gawk -v ___="${__}" -Mbe  "${f}" &)  

  0.36s user 3     out9: 13.2GiB 0:02:06 [ 106MiB/s] [ 106MiB/s]
```

- Using only 5 instances of `gawk` with `big-integer` package `gnu-GMP`, each with a designated subset of leading digit(s) of the prime number,

  —- it managed to calculate the full precision squaring of those primes in just ***2 minutes 6 seconds***, yielding an unsorted `13.2 GB` output file

if it can square that quickly, then merely grouping by `account_id` should be a walk in the park

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html
   You could import the data, create required indexes and then run queries normally. No dependencies except for the python itself.
2. https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html
3. If you have to query raw data every time and you are limited by simple python only, then you can either write a code to read it manually and yield matched rows or use a helper like this:

```py
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table
from convtools import conversion as c

iterable_of_matched_rows = (
    Table.from_csv("tmp/in.csv", header=True)
    .filter(c.col("account_id") == "1")
    .into_iter_rows(dict)
)
```

However this won't be faster than reading 100M row csv file with `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 0):

With [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/) the complete 100M rows CSV file (1.8GB) can easily fit in the memory of a regular desktop computer and run whatever SQL queries on it in matter of seconds

Here is the few steps:

```
CREATE TABLE result AS SELECT * from read_csv_auto('data.csv');
```

For the of a demo, I generated the data with the following commands

```
CREATE TABLE result (timestamp UINTEGER, account_id UINTEGER, data REAL);                                                                                                                                
Run Time (s): real 0.000 user 0.000180 sys 0.000000                                                                                                                                                        
INSERT INTO result(timestamp,account_id,data)  (SELECT floor(random()*100000::UINTEGER), floor(random()*60000::USMALLINT), round(random()*1000,2)::REAL AS s FROM range(0, 100000000, 1));               
Run Time (s): real 8.242 user 7.732149 sys 0.509185
```

it took 8 seconds to generate a table with 100M lines in memory

the SUMMARIZE command can show some statistics on this table

```
SUMMARIZE SELECT * from result;
```

| column_name | column_type | min | max | approx_unique | avg | std | q25 | q50 | q75 | count | null_percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| timestamp | UINTEGER | 0 | 99999 | 99492 | 49999.41741353 | 28866.929417142343 | 25033 | 50009 | 74979 | 100000000 | 0.0% |
| account_id | UINTEGER | 0 | 59999 | 59997 | 30001.15393498 | 17322.073797863097 | 15009 | 29984 | 44990 | 100000000 | 0.0% |
| data | FLOAT | 0.0 | 1000.0 | 99244 | 499.94853794041455 | 288.66460489423315 | 250.03180520538703 | 500.3373948166276 | 749.9874392136103 | 100000000 | 0.0% |

```
Run Time (s): real 6.711 user 75.795873 sys 0.086779
```

you can export the complete CSV file or just a part for a specific account

```
COPY (SELECT timestamp,data from result WHERE account_id=1234) TO 'result_1234.csv' (FORMAT CSV);
```

Here is the memory usage on my computer (less than 2GB!!!)

```
PRAGMA database_size;
```

| database_name | database_size | block_size | total_blocks | used_blocks | free_blocks | wal_size | memory_usage | memory_limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| memory | 0 bytes | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 bytes | 1.9GB | 26.8GB |