# Split a csv file into multiple files based on a pattern

Tags: python, csv, unix, split

I have a csv file with the following structure:

```
time,magnitude
0,13517
292.5669,370
620.8469,528
0,377
832.3269,50187
5633.9419,3088
20795.0950,2922
21395.6879,2498
21768.2139,647
21881.2049,194
0,3566
292.5669,370
504.1510,712
1639.4800,287
46709.1749,365
46803.4400,500
```

I'd like to split this csv file into separate csv files, like the following:

File 1:

```
time,magnitude
0,13517
292.5669,370
620.8469,528
```

File 2:

```
time,magnitude
0,377
832.3269,50187
5633.9419,3088
20795.0950,2922
21395.6879,2498
```

and so on..

I've read several similar posts (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489078/how-to-split-a-huge-csv-file-based-on-content-of-first-column?rq=3), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951393/split-large-csv-text-file-based-on-column-value?rq=3), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847803/splitting-csv-file-based-on-a-particular-column-using-python)), but they all search for specific values in a column and save each groups of values into a separate file. However, in my case, the values of time column are not the same. I'd like to split base on a condition: `If time = 0, save that row and all subsequent rows in a new file until the next time =0`.

Can someone please let me know how to do this?

Comment: You're still looking for a specific value, when time is equal to zero. Aren't you?

Comment: (1) Please add a sample CSV. These are not the raw data as you want to use it. (2) Do you insist in a python solution? — This looks like a classical `awk` solution.

Comment: @GIZ: yes, but I don't want to only save the rows where time = 0, but also the subsequent rows until the next time =0

Comment: @dodrg: 1) I'm not sure how to attach a csv file here, but my csv file have the exact same structure as I showed in my question. 2) no, I am fine with any solution :)

Comment: So the columns are "tab separated" / one or multiple / mixed tab+space?

Comment: @dodrg, oh, no sorry the columns are comma separated.

Comment: You can copy/paste the csv (or a portion of it) directly into your question exactly like it is from the file. Nothing you have posted here is CSV format (there are no commas). Instead, you posted a different representation of the data. You should post the raw data exactly as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input_file.csv", sep=",") # <- change the sep if needed

for n, g in df.groupby(df["time"].eq(0).cumsum()):
    g.to_csv(f"file_{n}.csv", index=False, sep=",")
```

Output :

```
    time  magnitude   # <- file_1.csv
  0.0000      13517
292.5669        370
620.8469        528

      time  magnitude # <- file_2.csv
    0.0000        377
  832.3269      50187
 5633.9419       3088
20795.0950       2922
21395.6879       2498
```

Answer (score 3):

datasplit.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN
{
    filename = "output_file_"
    fileext = ".csv"
    FS = ","

    c = 0
    file = filename c fileext
    getline
    header = $0
}
{
    if ($1 == 0){
        c = c + 1
        file = filename c fileext
        print header > file
        print $0 >> file
    } else {
        print >> file
    }
}
```

Make the file executable:

```bash
chmod +x datasplit.awk
```

Start in the folder where the data shall be written:

```
datasplit.awk datafile
```

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty to create a few more data similar to the ones you provided to test my solution. Moreover, I didn't use an input `csv` file but a `dataframe` instead. Here is my solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a random DataFrame

data = {
   'time': [0, 292.5669, 620.8469, 0, 832.3269, 5633.9419, 20795.0950, 21395.6879, 0, 230.5678, 456.8468, 0, 784.3265, 5445.9452, 20345.0980, 21095.6898],
   'magnitude': [13517, 370, 528, 377, 50187, 3088, 2922, 2498, 13000, 369, 527, 376, 50100, 3087, 2921, 2497]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to split a DataFrame based on a pattern

def split_dataframe_by_pattern(df, output_prefix):
    file_count = 1
    current_group = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)  # Initialize the current group

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['time'] == 0 and not current_group.empty:  # If time = 0 and the current group is not empty, create a new file
            output_file = f'{output_prefix}_{file_count}.csv'

            # Save the current group to the new file

            current_group.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
            current_group = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)  # Reset the current group
            file_count += 1

        # Use pandas.concat to append the row to the current group
        current_group = pd.concat([current_group, row.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)

    # Save the last group to a file

    current_group.to_csv(f'{output_prefix}_{file_count}.csv', index=False)

# Example usage:
output_prefix = 'output_file'
split_dataframe_by_pattern(df, output_prefix)
```

My output is four `csv` files:

`output_file_1.csv`

```
time,magnitude
0.0,13517.0
292.5669,370.0
620.8469,528.0
```

`output_file_2.csv`

```
time,magnitude
0.0,377.0
832.3269,50187.0
5633.9419,3088.0
20795.095,2922.0
21395.6879,2498.0
```

`output_file_3.csv`

```
time,magnitude
0.0,13000.0
230.5678,369.0
456.8468,527.0
```

`output_file_4.csv`

```
time,magnitude
0.0,376.0
784.3265,50100.0
5445.9452,3087.0
20345.098,2921.0
21095.6898,2497.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with panda very easily like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv")
last_idx = 0
file_idx = 0
for i,time in enumerate(df.time):
    if time == 0 and i != 0:
        df.iloc[last_idx:i].to_csv(f"mydata_{file_idx}.csv", index=None)
        file_idx += 1
        last_idx = i
df.iloc[last_idx:].to_csv(f"mydata_{file_idx}.csv", index=None)
```